# Как задать условие: "если стек пустой"?

Tags: c++, условия

```
for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++)
{
    if(str[j] != '+' && str[j] != '-' & str[j] != '*' && str[j] != '/') 
            cout << (char)(arr[k++] = str[j]) << " ";

    if(str[j] == '+' && str[j] == '-') x = 25;
    if(str[j] == '*' && str[j] == '/') y = 50;

    if(str[j] == '+' || str[j] == '-' || str[j] == '*' || str[j] == '/')
    {
        OPZ.push(str[j]);
        count++;
    }

    if(count > 1)
    {
        if(str[j] == x) OPZ.push(str[j]);
        else
            while(str[j] != y || str[j] != 0) // вот тут dvtcnj str[j] != 0 как задать условие: или стек пустой???
            {
                (char)(arr[k++] = str[j]);
                OPZ.pop();
            }
}
```

Как мне задать условие: или стек пустой в коде, рядом дописал комментарий. Не могу додуматься почему-то.

Comment: [Закон противоречия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Закон противоречия), условие a==b && a!=b всегда ложно

Answer (score 8):

У стека, если рассматривать его как [**абстрактную структуру данных,**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) есть соответствующий метод `isempty,` который и должен отвечать на интересующий вас вопрос:

> `init: -> Stack`
>
> `push: N x Stack -> Stack`
>
> `top: Stack -> (N U ERROR)`
>
> `remove: Stack -> Stack`
>
> **`isempty: Stack -> Boolean`**

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать а если я напишу функцию внутри класса void empty() { top == 0; или stack_array == 0 }, то как я могу проверить его в мейне? ну чтобы если empty() - правда, то что то делать ???

Comment: Да, конечно, можете. Главное, чтоб ф-ция член класса не была private, а public.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(str[j] == '+' && str[j] == '-') x = 25;

if(str[j] == '*' && str[j] == '/') y = 50;
```

Что-то смущает меня в этих условиях. Безотчетное что-то. А Вас?

Comment: @BuilderC, мрак...